# Prime number detector failing on some numbers?

Tags: python

```
def is_prime(x):
    list1 = []
    count = 1
    if x < 0:
        return False
    elif x == 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    for item in range(x):
        list1.append(x - count)
        count += 1 
        if count == x:
            list1.remove(1)
    for item in list1:
        if x / item == 1:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

This is failing on some numbers and I am unsure why.  I'm pretty sure it is mostly a problem with my math, or maybe my understanding of prime numbers?  I am learning through code academy, so feel free to hint me in the right direction instead of giving me the outright answer.  Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: What algorithm are you trying to use to check if a number is prime? This returns `False` for everything greater than 2...

Comment: `x / item` will be 1 if x == item.  If x == 2 * item, it'll return 2.  Just saying...you're not going to get factors very successfully like that.

Comment: in the last if, when x is 20 and item is 10 you should return False. In general you might want to use modulus and you only need to test for number up to sqrt(x)

Comment: what is a prime number? How do you define it?

Comment: ahhh.  I see that my last if is a gaping idiocy.

Comment: try `(x % item == 0)` or, `int(x / item) == (x / item)`.

Comment: did you test the first for loop?  I don't think it does what you were imagining.  For `x=10` it leaves `list1=[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Python 2, and the difference of divide operation between Python 3 and Python 2 causes your problem. In Python 2, ordinary division gets a integer, e.g 5/4=1, while in Python 3, 5/4=1.25. So, in python 2, 5 can be treated as non prime number in your function.

Instead of division, you can try other mathematical operation like module `%` to do the judgement.

Comment: not to mention that the expression `x / item` can be 10, or 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def is_prime(x):
    count = 0
    if x < 0:
        return False
    elif x == 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(1,int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(x)))+1): #only looks up to sqrt(x)
        if not x % n: #if n is divisor of x then it is factor
            count += 1
        if count > 1: #if we have 2 or more factors then it isn't a prime 
            return False
    return True
```

Some tests:

```
print(all(is_prime(p) for p in [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 23, 29, 41, 43, 47, 61, 67, 83, 89, 101, 113, 131]))
print(any(is_prime(np) for np in [1,4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,16]))

>>> 
True
False
```

Comment: @wim You're right, fixed up the sqrt() bit, the range was missing by 1, had to increment

Comment: I still think it's an inelegant solution.  If you check the divisibility by 2 explicitly first, then you can step the range through only odd numbers and do half the work on large numbers.  Also it's better to use `any`/`all` which are short-circuiting rather than continuing through the entire range needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) which returns the remainder when dividing two numbers

```
>>> 4 % 2
0
>>> 5 % 2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I've only tested on a few numbers:

```
def is_prime(n):

    i = 2
    sq_root_n = n**0.5
    if n <= 0:
        return False
    while i < sq_root_n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def is_prime(x):
    maxdiv = x - 1
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    elif x >= 2:
        for n in range(2,maxdiv):
            if x % n == 0:
                print '%d is not prime. I divided it by %d' % (x, n)
                return False
        else:
            return True
```